What is a minimal working version of Cal-Heatmap?
From the documentation I would guess that this code should work:
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>blah</title>
<!-- <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- v6 is also supported -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/cal-heatmap/dist/cal-heatmap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/cal-heatmap/dist/cal-heatmap.css">

</head>
<body>
<p>I'm the content</p>
<div id="cal-heatmap"></div>
<script>
    const cal = new CalHeatmap();
    cal.paint({});
    render(<div id="cal-heatmap"></div>);
</script>
</body>
</html>

However, there is an issue with the render function (the browser says Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'). This issues gets solved by removing the render line, but then more complex version of the heatmap are not possible
I deducted the minimal version from the website, but the documentation does not speak about the render function. Furthermore, there are no indication on the web of this issue.

Just remove this line: render(<div id="cal-heatmap"></div>);

How can this be the correct solution if more advanced versions ( e.g. https://cal-heatmap.com/docs/showcase ) heavily rely on render?

@bas Note that render() is from react or other framework or library. Check the docs on the example you used.

@GetSet I agree. But I was unable to find any reference to it in the docs.

I looked too. Its unfortunate that they dont document their usage of it (React) explicitly. Maybe the sign of the times to just assume. Maybe its buried somewhere on their site. Nonetheless, it is React code. You dont need it (nor would it work) for your example since you're not setup for react, and works by embedding the div directly in your html.
